# The § character

Tags: symbols, unicode

I need information about § character. I have seen it used for numbering (equivalent to nº) and as a separator. Which is its name or code? Where can it be used?

Comment: @Stefan: what has this character to do with unicode? It is already part of the extended ASCII

Comment: @Herbert: {unicode} has been the original tag chosen by the questioner. I just added the tag {symbols}. And the connection to Unicode is, that it is encoded as U+00A7 in Unicode, which is part of the question.

Comment: @Herbert: There's no such thing as "extended ASCII." Perhaps you mean one of the ISO 8859 character encodings?

Comment: @TH: The original ASCII had 128 characters and it was _extended_ to 256.

Comment: @Herbert: Not quite. ASCII has 128 characters. There are many 8 bit character encodings that include ASCII as a subset. Those given in ISO 8859 are common examples. ASCII was never extended. My guess is you're thinking of ISO 8859-1, also called Latin-1.

Comment: @TH: No, there are tons of charsets which includes ASCII and what we called all extended ASCII, that maybe, of course, ISO 8859. But there are also others, also extended from the ASCII. Remember, that I never said, that there is acommon charset which is _named_ Extended ASCII. It means only that the § character is defined using the eighth bit, it is in the upper half of the 256 characters.

Comment: @Herbert: I think you're saying that every 8-bit character encoding that is a superset of ASCII is called extended ASCII. That's not really correct. It's true you never said there was a single one, but you did write "The original ASCII had 128 characters and it was _extended_ to 256." That's implying that there's some standard extension called extended ASCII, which there simply is not. Finally, the claim that § is in the upper half isn't correct either. ISO 8859-11 and TIS 620 are 8-bit character encoding that contain ASCII (maybe you'd call them extended ASCII) but they lack the character.

Comment: @Herbert: By the way, if you want me to be notified of your comments, you have to include the period. Apparently it takes at least three characters.

Comment: @TH. sigh ... I gave it up. You already know, what was meant. And, by the way, it was me who _extended_ the ASCII to use the eighth bit for printers ...

Comment: Nobody else has noted this so far … I find it odd that you have seen this used in place of “nº”. This isn’t its conventional use, and in fact I don’t think most people would recognize it to mean that so be careful when using it like this.

Comment: @Konrad: It depends on the language. In French (see for example the Bourbaki books), it's common to use § when referring to section numbers and n° for subsections.

Comment: @Philippe: my point exactly: **section** numbers. That’s because § is the *section* symbol, not only in French. But n° in French is much more general and not only applied to (sub-) section numbering.

Comment: @Konrad: sorry, I had misunderstood your point. We both agree that n° can be used in contexts where § would not be appropriate at all, but there are also some contexts where interchanging § and n° is not that problematic (e.g. using §1.3.4 instead of n°1.3.4), and that could be what Fernando meant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) sign, you can typeset it with TeX/LaTeX by typing `\S`.

Comment: not only TeX/LaTeX, also with the other ones

Comment: @Herbert Right should have said (All)TeX!

Answer (score 7):

```
\S
```

with a correct inputencoding you can input it directly from your keyboard, if present.

Answer (score 3):

U+00A7 SECTION SIGN

General Character Properties

In Unicode since: 1.1
Unicode category: Symbol, Other

Various Useful Representations
Here is what I have (from Linux's character map utility):

UTF-8: 0xC2 0xA7
UTF-16: 0x00A7

C octal escaped UTF-8: \302\247
XML decimal entity: §

Annotations and Cross References

Notes:

### • paragraph sign in some European usage

Unicode  has several other section marks, but they are not as common, e.g.,
U+1360 ETHIOPIC SECTION MARK, Rejang section mark, and more.

Answer (score 1):

I found this character listed as `\NAK` and it's shown on page 72 in Scott Pakin's [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), Table 227: ASCII Control Characters (CP437). Apparently is a control character, part of the first 33 non-printing control characters (now mostly obsolete) that affect how text and space is processed.

This character is sometimes used for adorning numbered titles of sub-sections of text in older books, this is how I started looking for it. And it is true you can get it very easy by using `\S`.